# How do I validate that user input is alphabetic or spaces in python?

Tags: python

How can I validate user input to restrict them in only entering alphabetical characters?
I currently have this while loop set up;

```
while True:
if message.isalpha():
    print ("You have chosen to " + decision.lower() + " " + message.lower() + ".")
    break
else:
    message = input("Please enter the message you wish to " + decision.lower() + " in alphabetical characters only.")
```

However the message I want to validate can contain spaces, and if a message is a sentence of only alphabetical characters the result will return false.

Comment: Rather than `str.isalpha`, write your own function that takes a string and returns `True` if it's OK and `False` otherwise, then use that.

Answer (score 2):

Use regular expressions

```
import re

if re.search("^[a-zA-Z\s]+$", message):
      print ("You have chosen to " + decision.lower() + " " + message.lower() + ".")
else:
     message = input("Please enter the message you wish to " + decision.lower() + " in alphabetical characters only.")
```

Explanation:

The function re.search tries to find a pattern in the variable message. If it finds, the code enters in the if clause. The pattern is defined by the regular expression "^[a-zA-Z\s]+$". To understand, let's divide the expression:

- **^** means the beginning of the string
- **a-z** means any character from a to z (lowercase)
- **A-Z** means any character from A to Z (uppercase)
- **\s** means whitespace
- **+** means one or more times
- **$** means the end of the string

Because, **a-z**, **A-Z** and **\s** are inside the brackets **[]**, it means **a-z** OR **A-Z** OR **\s**. Using the **+**, I defined that everything inside the brackets can appear one or more times. So, the code is trying to search any lowercase, uppercase or whitespaces appearing one or more times.

Comment: I tired it and it works perfectly, however i do not completely understand what you have posted. Could you please explain what                               "if re.search("^[a-zA-Z\s]+$", message):" does

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set`:

```
import string

if set(message).issubset(string.ascii_lowercase + " "):
    print "Good one"
```

You can use `string.ascii_letters` for both cases, etc.

Answer (score 0):

After tests, my most efficient way (in term of time) seems to delete space and use `str.isalpha`:

```
if 'my text'.replace(' ', '').isalpha():
    print 'Good one'
```

Timings comparaison:

```
>>> # My answer:
>>> def test()
        'my text'.replace(' ', '').isalpha()
>>> %timeit test()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 336 ns per loop

>>> # Stuart's answer:
>>> def test()
        set(message).issubset(string.ascii_lowercase + " ")
>>> %timeit test()
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.17 us per loop

>>> # Yuri's answer:
>>> reg = re.compile("^[a-zA-Z\s]+$")
>>> def test()
        reg.search('my text')
>>> %timeit test()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 504 ns per loop
```